# How to sort objects by amount of references with Extbase 6.2

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

In my extbase 6.2 extension I want the user to select something from a select-input, I want the items to be ordered by usage.
I sorted my objects doing this before:

```
/**
 * The repository for Expertises
 */
class ExpertiseRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository {

    // Order by BE sorting
    protected $defaultOrderings = array(
        'name' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING
    );

}
```

But now I want to sort them by the amount of references - and then as a second ordering by their name. I have no idea where that references field is or what it's name is - I've just seen it in the backend here:
[image: References in Typo Backend]
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

These references are stored in the so-called refindex, which is located in the table `sys_refindex`.

So to get the count, you need to `LEFT JOIN` your table with sys_refindex, like so:

```
SELECT t.uid, …, COUNT(*) AS refcount
FROM tx_myext_table t
  LEFT JOIN sys_refindex ri
    ON t.uid = ri.recuid AND ri.tablename = "tx_myext_table"
GROUP BY ri.uid, ri.tablename
```

A little background on the refindex: TYPO3 handles that internally and updates it on every record change, when it is done via the official API (e.g. when saving a record in the backend forms).

Comment: Will it also be updated, if records are manipulated via FE (Extbase). E.g. relations are added and repoository `update()` method is called? Or one needsto run this task via CLI: `typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh lowlevel_refindex -e`?

Comment: Also I'm curious if these are really numbers from `sys_refindex` and not from the column itself, bcs afaik TYPO3 stores numbers of relations exactly in relation field. So for task of sorting by reltaion number it might not be needed to join the `sys_refindex` table.